# Как при выборе значения из select поместить value в массив?

Tags: javascript

Изначально в селекте ---, после того как я выбираю какой-либо элемент списка, это число должно залететь в массив. При изменении, старое значение из массива должно удаляться, т.е. перезаписываться.

Comment: А теперь лаконично, чётко и по русски.

Comment: Не совсем понятно насчёт массива, ну да бог с ним. А в чём ваш вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот здесь про select'ы: http://www.tigir.com/javascript_select.htm

```
<select onchange = "mass[key] = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" ...>
...
```

Или тебя не поняли.